# iOS app deployment issue

Tags: ios, deployment

Our company uses over the air adhoc deployment.  We do this by exporting .ipa file and linking that file on a web server in a .plist file.  This allows us to send them a URL link to a provisioned device and install a new version of the app for beta testing.  This process has worked fine until iOS 8.0.1.  When the user clicks on the link to install the app, they get a message saying "Do you want to install the app?" and when they click YES nothing happens.  The app never gets installed.  Is there a work around for this?  How can we do over-the-air adhoc install without being an enterprise developer?  Is there something that needs to change in the formatting of the .plist file?

Comment: Are you delivering the IPA fie via HTTPS?  Does the server have a certificate that is valid and trusted by the device?

Comment: Yes. I am  delivering the IPA fie via HTTPS. The server have a certificate that is valid and trusted by the device. In fact it works fine in ios 8 , ios 8.0.1 devices. It is an issue with ios 8.1 devices

Comment: can one of the gurus have a look at this please